# Appsee couldn't locate an Android Manifest file

Tags: android, google-fabric, appsee

When trying to build my project with the Appsee SDK, I get the error:

```
Appsee couldn't locate an Android Manifest file.
```

Strangely, it was working fine for a while and this issue cropped up suddenly. I've tried fixing file permissions in macOS Finder and I've tried clearing caches and rebuilding.

```
dependencies {
    //implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.appsee:appsee-android:+'
    implementation('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.appsee.appsee-plugin'
```

In my manifest:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.appsee.ApiKey" android:value="my-key" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should contact Appsee's support at support@appsee.com.

In the meantime, you may want to put the `apply plugin: 'com.appsee.appsee-plugin'` line in a comment. The Appsee SDK will still work.

Comment: Contacted Appsee support a few days ago and am waiting for a response. Commented out the plugin for now and it's building fine :D. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Frogger any updates on this? Did you get a response from AppSee?

Comment: @Dawit a hotfix is available from support@appsee.